# MFC program using visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am getting the following warning after I debug the MFC based windows application(visual C++). The problem is that it does not display the window. Why is it so?

```
Warning: m_pMainWnd is NULL in CWinApp::Run - quitting application.
The program '[2616] new.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The code is:

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

class myframe:public CFrameWnd
{
public:
myframe()
{
    Create(0,TEXT("On single Left Mouse Button Click"));
}
void OnLButtonDown(UINT flag,CPoint pt)
{
    CClientDC d(this);
    d.SetTextColor(RGB(0,0,255));
    d.TextOutW(pt.x,pt.y,TEXT("Hello"),5);
}
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(myframe,CFrameWnd)
ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

class myapp:public CWinApp
{
public:
    int InitInsatnce()
    {
        myframe *p;
        p=new myframe;
        p->ShowWindow(3);
        m_pMainWnd=p;
        return 1;
    }
};
myapp a;
```

Comment: first: myframe()
second, can we see the code for myframe?

Comment: Oh boy do I wish I had edit powers...

Comment: isn't "InitInsatnce" a typo? Do you have this in your real code?

Answer (score 4):

Fix the typo: `InitInsatnce` should be `InitInstance` then your window will be initialised and displayed.